# Changing user nickname on_member_update in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to prevent my friends from changing my nickname on our server (everyone is an admin). I've added following lines to our bot to change my nickname to previous one after someone makes a change:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print("old nick: ", before.nick)
    print("new nick: ", after.nick)
    if before.nick == "exampleNickname":
        await after.edit(nick=before.nick)
```

I've added two prints to check what's wrong and console displays:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOMH3.png)
Why before is equal to None?

Comment: Is your current name a guild-specific nickname, or is it the name associated with your account as a whole?

Comment: If your user haven't nickname in your channel before you start the bot, that `before.nick` return `None` because he isn't nickname before. `None` shows that `nickname` removed or not set.